# Spearman rank correlation with missing values?

Tags: correlation

I have two list of words which are ordered by the number of occurrences

The ordering was generated by counting each word in two files sampled at different point in times.

I would like to calculate spearman to see how well the order of the first file was found in the second file.

for instance:

File a: 1) is 2) went 3) work

File b: 1) is 2) work 3) went

Because the ordering is different I would not achieve a score of 1.0 but yet one that would suggest that these two samples are rather similar

My problem are now missing values. A word of file A might not exist in the file B. Can I use spearman rank in this case? Or would be another correlation measure better suited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to rank, in your application, you don't need to have missing values.  When a word has an occurrence in one file but not in the other, you can give it last ranking in the other file (or equal last ranking for multiple missing values).

However, I am not sure of the effect on the Spearman value of lots of missing values (lots of tied last ranks).  You might instead consider using a standard correlation/regression on the raw *relative* frequencies, instead of the Spearman coefficient.

Example...

Say file x has m=113 words and file y has n=234.  We can create a table of relative word frequencies like so:

`word              x        y

 is             5/113    23/234
 the            4/113    45/234
 a              4/113    17/234
 farnarkling    1/113     0/234
 elbow          0/113     2/234
 ...
 ===============================
 TOTAL        113/113   234/234`

You would then calculate:

`word              x         y        u=x*y      v=x*x

 is             5/113    23/234    115/26442   25/12769
 the            4/113    45/234    180/26442   16/12769
 a              4/113    17/234     68/26442   16/12769
 farnarkling    1/113     0/234      0/26442    1/12769
 elbow          0/113     2/234      0/26442    0/12769
 ...
 ========================================================
 TOTAL        113/113   234/234  s=(sum of u) t=(sum of v)`

Your answer is given by s/t.  A value close to m/n implies a good correspondence.

Some possibly useful links are:

https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression