# r cor spearman handle missing value

Tags: r

I want to calculate the correlation between variables which aren't normally distributed, so I will use Spearman. There are some missing values and I don't know how to handle them. 
In the cor function concerning Spearman it says:

```
"In the case of missing values, the ranks are calculated depending on the value of use, either based on complete observations, or based on pairwise completeness with reranking for each pair."
```

It also say:

```
"For cov and var, "pairwise.complete.obs" only works with the "pearson" method."
```

So how do I set "or based on pairwise completeness with reranking for each pair" as a criteria for "use"?

cor(df, method="spearman", use= WHAT?) :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spearman rank correlation with missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323239/spearman-rank-correlation-with-missing-values)

Comment: Did you try: `cor(df, method="spearman", use= "pairwise.complete.obs")`